# Data getting corrupted in stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

This may be trivial but I could not understand why it is happening.

I am trying to append the data of "double" type into stringstream but it seems to be getting corrupted. Any insights on this?

```
for (int metalNum = 0; metalNum< r_maxMetalNum; metalNum++)
{
    if ((unsigned int)metalNum >= metalLayerV.size())  return false;

    if (metalLayerV[metalNum].getThick() >= 0)
    {
        if (metalNum != 0)  metalThickSS << ",";
        cout << "JJJJ..."  << metalLayerV[metalNum].getThick() << "\n";
        metalThickSS << std::setprecision(3) << metalLayerV[metalNum].getThick();
    }
}

cout << "Hello " << metalThickSS.str() << "\n";
```

Output is:

```
JJJJ...0.000000
JJJJ...0.000000
JJJJ...0.000000
JJJJ...0.000000
JJJJ...0.000000
JJJJ...0.000000
JJJJ...0.000000
JJJJ...0.000000
JJJJ...0.000000
JJJJ...0.000000
Hello 4.45e-321,4.45e-321,4.45e-321,4.45e-321,4.45e-321,4.45e-321,4.45e-321,4.45e-321,6.18e-320,6.18e-320
```

Thanks all for your comments. I found out that it was actually a trivial issue. I just need to use fixed and showpoint with output stringstream.

Comment: What is corrupted? Strings like 4.45e-321 are the values for metalLayerV[metalNum].getThick(), right?

Comment: @Mine Well, they probably aren't right, since `DBL_MIN` is probably around `2.225E-308`.  When you end up with subnormals like this, there's _usually_ something wrong in the way you're calculating them.  Or in your choice of dimensions---measuring the thickness of aluminum foil in parsecs (although there's enough range in an IEEE double that even that won't cause problems).

Comment: @WernerHenze I don't think that the precision is the issue.  The format of the output to `std::cout` suggests that it has been set to `fixed` format, so the precision specifies the number of digits after the decimal (and would have to be something like `320` for him to start seeing non-zero values).

Comment: The problem is - "When I printed the value of thickness in line starting with JJJJ, it printed out correctly "0.00000" and this is what I want. But when I appended these values of thickness in stringstream, it printed out as 4.4e-321.

Comment: @James Kanze But it's possible to print values less than 2.225E-308. At least on Ubuntu 12.04, `cout<<DBL_MIN / 10000000000000*2;` prints `4.45e-321`

Comment: @Mine Of course.  This is because of gradual underflow.  If you're getting such values, however, there is a loss of precision, and you probably should review your algorithm.

Comment: @crazy_prog That's because your using different formatting parameters when printing.  When you print in the line starting with JJJJ, you're using fixed format; when you print in the stringstream, you're using the default format (which doesn't have a name in C++, but corresponds to `%g` in C).

Answer (score 0):

You don't show much of the significant code, so I can only
guess, but a priori, it looks like you've set standard out to
fixed format, so it will only show six digits after the decimal
(and any value less than `0.0000005` will display as
`0.000000`), but your `ostringstream` is still set to the
default (or to scientific format).  And supposing IEEE floating
point, the values you are displaying show gradual underflow,
which means that they are very, very close to `0.0`, but not
`0.0` (and that there was probably some carelessness involved in
the way they were calculated).

Comment: I did nothing significant, just tried to print out the values using simple variable and with stringstream. Both are supposed to print the same values, but doesn't seemed to be. Although I used the same value "metalLayerV[metalNum].getThick()" with cout and stringstream.

Comment: @crazy_prog Both do print the same values.  But using different formats, so they _look_ different (and are rounded differently).  From the output, it is evident that the output to `std::cout` was done using fixed format, but that to the `ostringstream` used either scientific or the default.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is caused by `cout << fixed` at somewhere else in your code.
Please see below code:

```
  double d = DBL_MIN / 10000000000000 * 2;
  cout << d << endl;
  cout << fixed;
  cout << d << endl;

  stringstream ss;
  ss << setprecision(3);
  ss << d;
  cout << ss.str() << endl;
```

It prints

```
4.44659e-321
0.000000
4.45e-321
```

This could be the only explanation of your output.